# Store objects entangled after assignment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

Once a user is logged in, I assign `state.user` to the value `this.$auth.user`. Why when I change a value in `state.user`, it's reflected in `this.$auth.user`, while USER_SETUP is never called again ? Is it a problem with the way I'm assigning the `state.user` object ?

`store/index.js`

```
export const mutations = {
  USER_SETUP(state) {
    console.log('USER SETUP');
    state.user = this.$auth.user;
  }
}
```

For instance, setting `state.user.foo = 'hello'` also sets `state.auth.user.foo` to `hello`.

Comment: Both variables point to the same object.  You are mutating the object both variables point to.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep):

```
state.user = _.cloneDeep(this.$auth.user);
```